# $$Error:Counterparty sent session rejection message at unexpected time with message class flow is not registered

Tags: corda

I want to make external service call by using oraclizer. So I m trying to run the example file given below:

[Example Oraclize](https://github.com/oraclize/corda-api.git)

After running, I'm getting an error--

> Counterparty sent session rejection message at unexpected time with message class it.oraclize.cordapi.flows.OraclizeQueryFlow is not registered

In the flow, OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow flow is called which in turn calls OraclizeQueryFlow. In this flow there is a sendAndReceive call which happens as follows:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC

class OraclizeQueryFlow (val datasource: String, val query: Any, val proofType: Int = 0, val delay: Int = 0) : FlowLogic<String>() {

companion object {

    object PROCESSING : ProgressTracker.Step("Submitting the query.")

    @JvmStatic
    fun tracker() = ProgressTracker(PROCESSING)

    @JvmStatic
    val console = loggerFor<OraclizeQueryFlow>()
}

override val progressTracker = tracker()

fun console(a: Any) = loggerFor<OraclizeQueryFlow>().info(a.toString())
// start OraclizeQueryFlow datasource: "URL", query: "json(https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=USD&tsyms=GBP).GBP", proofType: 16, delay: 0
// start OraclizeQueryFlow datasource: identity, query: hello, proofType: 0, delay: 0
@Suspendable
override fun call(): String {

    val oraclize = serviceHub.identityService
            .wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(OraclizeUtils.getNodeName()) as Party

    progressTracker.currentStep = PROCESSING
    val session = initiateFlow(oraclize)

    val query = Query(datasource, query, delay, proofType)
    val queryId = session.sendAndReceive<String>(query).unwrap { it }

    console("Query id: $queryId")

    return queryId
}
}
```

On checking logs I happened to find out that the sendAndReceive call is throwing this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is Mauro from Oraclize, are you using the public testnet of Corda? If not, you should follow this  [guide](https://docs.corda.net/corda-testnet-intro.html) to be able to use our service. If you are using it, then you should wait a couple of working days as we are still testing the service on the new testnet.